# Constructing an in-place sorting algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, in-place

I don't understand what is meant by in-place algorithms. If I were to implement, say some sort of sorting algorithm like rearranging a list with negative numbers at the beginning and positive numbers after. Can I still use basic functions such as append, if-statements or is the whole point of in-place to simply manipulate the input to fit my needs?

Say I have a list `A = [-2,0,3,-1]` and I want to sort it to: `A=[-2,-1,0,3]` the order of the elements themselves don't matter as long as positive and negative numbers are separated.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-insertion-sort/

Comment: Is that an in-place algorithm?

Comment: Inplace means you modify the actual object. Without inplace you get a copy of the object with the operation performed, such as sorting.

Comment: "in-place" means it doesn't create a new list for the results.

Comment: `arr[j+1] = arr[j]` is modifying the array in place.

Comment: _Can I still use basic functions such as append, if-statements or is the whole point of in-place to simply manipulate the input to fit my needs?_ Appending I understand, but why are if statements in there? Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of an algorithm that will sort a list in place. In line 6, two elements of the list trade places. Here's the code :

```
A = [-2, 0, 3, -1]
length = len (A)
for a in range (length) :
    for b in range (length) :
        if A [a] < A [b] :
            A [a], A [b] = A [b], A [a] 
print (A)
```